# I think the bridge-between-planets question was closed improperly as a duplicate

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

This weekend, we have [a question about how to build a bridge between two planets](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/64926/is-it-possible-to-build-a-bridge-between-planets). That was closed today as a duplicate of [this question about whether there is enough material to build a bridge between stars](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/34279/building-a-bridge-to-the-stars).

The two questions are related but definitely are not duplicates... if you read the answers of the older question, you'll find no answer to the new question. The new question wants to know how it could be built. The old one just asked for handwavium "is there enough material."

I would like the newer question reopened. Can I get the community to please re-evaluate?

Comment: It appears your request has already been seen to.  The question is currently opened

Comment: Usually, when this happens, the new question will include an explicit reference to the other and a statement of just how this is distinguished from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question has been reopened. Thanks.

Comment: Please accept this if you feel the issue has been resolved, so that the system knows that the question has been answered.